# How to fix GTK3 scrollbar behavior

Tags: gtk3, scrolling, scrollbar

I have removed the overlay scrollbars.

How can I configure GTK3 scrollbar clicking behavior?

GTK3 applications scrollbars behave strangely under Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04. This also happens with Fedora 17 and 18.

When I left-click anywhere above or below the thumb, it jumps to that position and starts dragging from there. The expected behavior is to scroll one page up or down.

When I right-click anywhere above or below the thumb, it scrolls one page up or down. That is the behavior I expect from left-clicking, the same way it works on GTK2 and QT applications.

Horizontal scrollbars have the same problem.

This is very bad for consistency.

Comment: You could try setting the scrollbar behaviour back to GTK2 with the following environment variable: `LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0`.

Comment: Thanks, this has been driving me insane ever since Firefox switched to gtk3.

Answer (score 48):

Found the answer here:

https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-948904-start-0.html

Edit (or create) the file:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

And add the following:

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.  I only use 2 or 3 gtk based applications, and having scrollbar behave differently in those than in all other applications was driving me nuts.

Comment: Doesn't work for GTK apps in KDE for me. Setting the property in `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` works for some applications but not all.

Comment: Works, this will fix GTK3 applications like gedit. It's sad that those config hacks are necessary to stop one of the most basic gui features (which have worked perfectly for decades) from misbehaving.

Comment: What genius thought up this "feature?" Middle-click already skips to the point clicked, and was broken by this.
`fix_broken_scroll_bar=true`

Comment: I'd like to implement the solution but I don't know how and where to edit (or create) the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini. Can you tell me what I have to do?

Comment: `~` means "your home directory", e.g. `/home/thierry`

Comment: This gtk3 setting works but it seems to break the ability to click on the timeline in the "Videos" (Totem) application to jump to any point in a video.  This could be considered a bug in "Videos" but if this non-default gtk3 setting has the potential to cause bugs in random gtk3 apps then it should be used with caution.

Comment: I don't use Totem, but maybe shift-click does the trick?

Comment: Seems not to be working for Ubuntu 20.04. As a safety net, I added that file in gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0 and gtk-4.0, and tried both true and false. Any clues what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

For GTK2 applications, I also noticed the scrollbar-warp behavior happens with the Adwaita theme (but not with the Greybird theme).  I fixed it for GTK2 by editing `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and changing the line

```
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = 1
```

to

```
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = 0
```

Comment: is there any user based setting file to set this option?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior appears tied to the desktop theme/style you select.  If you install the `gtk2-engines-xfce` package and then select one of the GTK2 themes (e.g. *Xfce-4.0*) from the *Appearance* settings, you will get GTK2-style scroll bars.

Unless you are particularly interested in using Adwaita or Greybird, I think the best (and certainly easiest) solution is just to pick a different theme.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to the Gtk2 scrollbar behavior can also be done on a **per-theme basis** by creating/including in the `~/.themes/myThemeName/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file, the [Settings] section, the scrollbar behavior switch

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

Comment: my distro seems to already have done this but the sliders are still behaving in a strange way with adwaita theme.