# How to fix the scrollbar new behaviour in Firefox

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

This question has already been asked ([How to fix GTK3 scrollbar behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295988/how-to-fix-gtk3-scrollbar-behavior)) but I don't know how to implement the answer: If I click in the scrollbar below or above the thumb it moves to the spot I just clicked. This happens in Firefox but not in Opera, the 2 browsers I use. Could someone explain how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is called "legacy scrolling" in gtk3: edit or create `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` to have

```
[Settings]
```

as the first line and

```
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false
```

on a subsequent line by itself. This works in most gtk3 applications but is said not to work in some. Alternatively, right-click instead of left-clicking works in all applications. And, if you want legacy scrolling system-wide, sudo edit `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` the same way.

Comment: I need a step by step guidance to implement the solution. Where should I edit or create ...?  I probably don't need to know what is gtk3. I just need to know the recipe to fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: I am still waiting for help. I could get used to the new scrollbar behaviour in Firefox but Opera is still using the previous behaviour. I use Opera for a lot of websites.  I'd like to have the same behaviour for both browsers.

Comment: Alternately I could change the scrollbar behaviour in Opera to match the one used with Firefox but how?

Comment: Opera now is based on the Chromium browser. It isn't exactly GTK3. So what applies to gtk3 apps may not apply to Opera.

Comment: Open a terminal window, and paste in this command: `printf "[Settings]\ngtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false\n" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

Comment: @TorKlingberg if the file already exists, the `[Settings]` line will be duplicated. I don't know whether that's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out where got changed; during GTK v3.6 merge.

Kristian Rietveld and Michael Natterer introduced the feature but both had since dropped out of GitHub.  :-/

https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/64324a5da080bee7ca42cfe53dadea9a882a9e64