# LibreOffice Writer Scrolling

Tags: libreoffice, scrolling

In Gnome 16.10
I cannot get smooth scrolling on the new LibreOffice Writer 5.2.2
It seems to scroll screen lengths instead of you know.. just scrolling.
It was fine in gnome 16.04
This "scrolling" refers to using two fingers on the touchpad.  It will do the same as pageup and pagedown, instead of line by line (like up and down arrows).
I remember and would like it to function like the up and down arrows work.. to move line by line.

Comment: Add `gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false` to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` to get [legacy scrolling](http://askubuntu.com/a/774203/248158).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, both false and true in the settings.ini in my home directory for /config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini  but it did not work.  Full shutdown and restart did not work.  This is a gtk 3.0 global change?  Who decided on this one?  I do not like this at all.  In fact, ubuntu needs smoother scrolling like apple.  Screen scrolling is hardly "smooth".

Answer (score 2):

I experienced exactly the same. I solved the problem by replacing libreoffice-gtk3 with libreoffice-gtk2 package

Comment: This might be a better answer if you explained exactly how yo accomplished that.

Comment: Thanks.  I have switched to Elementary Loki OS.  without a glitch.  Works fine.  I think gtk3 also has international typing problems.  I am able to type freely in Sanskrit keyboard now, but not so in Anki which is gtk3 (I think). eOS is sooo cool and smooth.  I checked your answer as good .  Cannot mark it as solved with honesty since I cannot test.  Thanks for solving though.