# scrollbar Issue in Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop

Tags: unity, mouse, scrolling, overlay-scrollbars, scrollbar

I have a scroll bar issue. There's a tiny pixel of margin to the right of the scroll bar, whenever I click on the scrollbar (on that margin) anywhere but *not* in the middle of it. The bar moves to where I clicked This is kinda annoying, any help?

[image: Cursor Scrollbar Issue]

When I hover on the scrollbar but *not* in the middle and click it. It kinda magnets the middle of the scrollbar to where I've clicked, another issue is that the cursor actually goes *beyond* the scrollbar to the right of it (a margin of around 1~2 pixels).

[image: Scrollbar Right Margin]

In this picture, I'm pointing to the right of the scrollbar, actually inside the scrollbar section. But the scrollbar is not in hover-mode However, when I click in that exact location the scrollbar scrolls to that location.

What I need to do is to remove that 1~2 pixels or margin, and turn off that scroll bar magnet problem so that when I click on any point on that seeker it doesn't scroll to the middle automatically.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/856125/edit) this post, and provide screenshot of your "glitched" scrollbar.

Comment: I can't take a screenshot because the cursor is not visible, I can't elaborate the problem without the cursor in the screenshot, that's Why I didn't post it .. is there anyway to work that out?

Comment: You can still edit your screenshots to highlight the mouse pointer position or the area described in your question. You can also use a screenshot tool that lets you include the mouse pointer in the image, e. g. *Gnome Screenshot*.

Comment: Re. the "scrollbar magnet problem", http://askubuntu.com/questions/774200/how-to-fix-the-scrollbar-new-behaviour-in-firefox/774203#774203 may be relevant.

Comment: @DKBose First problem solve, now no magnets, what about the second problem?

Comment: It's possibly a theme issue. You may try another theme or edit your existing one, if that's possible, to have `-GtkRange-trough-border: 0;` instead of a higher value. The file to be edited should be your theme's `gtk-widgets.css`.

Comment: @DKBose Thank you sir very much, problem solved, it took me sometime to learn about theming and .gresource file handling, but managed to work it out at last .. Thank you very much sir :))

Comment: You can post what you did as an answer. It will be helpful to others!

Comment: Done :) .. A review would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) the problem is solve, and this is what I did..
To fix the slider magnet problem, I installed a tool called "Unity Tweak Tool"

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

Launch the app, then choose "Scrolling" from the "System" section, then choose "Legacy" option instead of the "Overlay" option in the "Scrollbars" section.

The second problem was with the "Numix" theme I'm using, the solution was to navigate to "/usr/share/themes/Numix\ Daily/" folder and make a copy of the folder on desktop and do this command:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx ~/Desktop/Numix\ Daily/*
```

Go inside the folder and open a folder "gtk-3.0", in that folder there's a file "gtk.gresource" and two other important files "gtk.css" and "gtk-dark.css", first extract the actual CSS code from the .gresource file using this command:

```
touch tempgtk.css
touch tempgtkdark.css
sudo gresource extract gtk.gresource /org/numixproject/gtk/dist/gtk.css >> tempgtk.css
sudo gresource extract gtk.gresource /org/numixproject/gtk/dist/gtk-dark.css >> tempgtkdark.css
```

Now open these two files "tempgtk.css" and "tempgtkdark.css" and find this line

> GtkRange-trough-border

There's a value for this class, it has to be 0, if it's not 0 then set it to 0 and save.
Now open up "gtk.css" and comment/replace the content of the file with the content of "tempgtk.css", do the same for "gtk-dark.css".
Now copy those two files from the folder on your desktop, and put them back using this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/themes/Numix\ Daily/gtk-3.0/*.css
sudo cp ~/Desktop/Numix\ Daily/gtk-3.0/gtk* /usr/share/themes/Numix\ Daily/gtk-3.0/
```

Do a reboot or just change the theme to Ambiance and then change back to Numix and it'll work :)