# How to make gnome-terminal scroll one page when clicking on the right scrollbar?

Tags: gnome-terminal, scrolling, scrollbar

When clicking on an area of the right scrollbar of `gnome-terminal` which is not the scroll bar/thumb it jumps to the relative position of the output (I enabled unlimited output).

Some applications only jump one page/viewport height up or down when clicking above the bar or below (currently only find NetBeans 8.2 output window as example) which is the behavior I'm looking for.

The scroll preferences for profiles all to hide the scrollbar, control scrolling on output or keystroke and to limit the output which doesn't match what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for this precise behavior, no workaround involving other input devices or GUI controls.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does it have to be click on scroll bar ? There's a keyboard shortcut for that, Ctrl+Shift+PgUp.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for you input. Yes, edited the question.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Also a good idea. I made my "I'm looking for this precise behavior" sentence more precise.

Comment: You should look for `GTK+` (or maybe `GNOME`) instuctions on how to configure the scrollbars. I'm not familiar with them to provide further help, sorry. `GNOME Terminal` doesn't do anything special with its scrollbars, just lets `GTK+` do whatever it wishes to do. So the behavior needs to be configured `GTK+`-wide, not in `GNOME Terminal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the scrollbar is common to all GTK applications and its configuration was described here: [How to fix GTK3 scrollbar behavior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295988/how-to-fix-gtk3-scrollbar-behavior)

Edit (or create) the file:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

And add the following:

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

Then restart the gnome-terminal for the change to become effective.