# How do I scroll slowly on Firefox, Document Viewer, etc.?

Tags: firefox, scrolling

I see no arrows at top and bottom of the right-hand scroll bar for doing this, only the scroll bar itself. With very long webpages or documents, using the scroll bar gives no fine control over scrolling up and down a single page or a few pages at one time.

With Document Viewer, I am trying to scroll up and down a single page of the PDF I am reading, because the whole page is not shown on the screen at one time. Even if I try to use the scroll bar to move up and down the page, the scroll bar doesn't move with the mouse pointer and the page inexplicably starts drifting up or down of it's own accord, out of my control.

English, please!

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/296406/248158 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show the side panel in the **pdf-viewer Evince**, you can use

the  [image] and [image] arrow keys of the keyboard

to scroll one page for each key-press. Otherwise, if you click in the page itself, and the whole page is not displayed, the same keys will scroll in small steps. (I think this is what you want.)

In **Firefox** the same keys will scroll in small steps. You can also use the scroll wheel of your mouse (if you have a mouse with a scroll-wheel).